# Display all service names matching a string pattern

Tags: powershell, windows-services

I'm trying to display the name (just the name) of all of the installed services that contain the string "SQL". For example, I want to see

- SQLAgent$SQL2008_R2
- SQLBrowser
- SQLWriter

So I try this:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Service
```

This displays all of the services, but as a list.

```
Exit Code : 0
Name      : ProtectedStorage
ProcessId : 664
StartMode : Manual
State     : Running
Status    : OK

Exit Code : 1077
Name      : QWAVE
ProcessId : 0
StartMode : Manual
State     : Stopped
Status    : OK
(etc...)
```

This is good, but I just want to see the name. So I type:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Service | select-object Name
```

And I get what I expect:

```
sppuinotfy
SQLAgent$SQL2008_RT
SQLBrowser
SQLWriter
SSDPSRV
(etc ..)
```

All is good. I take the next step of filtering the names to only include SQL related ones:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Service | select-object Name | select-string -pattern 'SQL'
```

And now it's confusing. Here is my output:

```
@{Name=BcmSqlStartupSvc}
@{Name=MSOLAP$SQL2008_R2}
@{Name=MSSQL$SQL2008_R2}
(etc ...)
```

Why am I getting this output, instead of just the names?
What should I be typing to get just the names?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve that is using `-Filter` Parameter

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_Service -Filter "Name LIKE '%SQL%'" | 
Select -ExpandProperty Name
```

In case, you want to go with your code only, here is the way you can modify it:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Service | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | 
Select-String -pattern 'SQL'
```

Edit: LIKE operator takes a few meta characters to support matching pattern.

`[]` - for range matching. For example, `Name LIKE '[a-f]%'` will list all services starting with any letter from a to f.

`^` - not. For example, `Name LIKE '[^a-f]%'` will list services that do not start with any letter from a to f.

`_` - matches one letter. For example, `Name LIKE 'S_L%'` will list services that start with S and followed by any letter.

Comment: Thanks. My next learning tasks is to understand the difference between "select-object -ExpandProperty Name" and "select-object {$_.Name}"

Answer (score 20):

You can use Get-Service instead of get-WMIObject and do it like this"

```
get-service sql* | select -expand name
```

Comment: To return (or list) multiple properties, use select-object and comma seperated properties like `get-service sql* | select-object name, DisplayName`

Answer (score 9):

```
Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "SQL"} |Select-Object Name
```

Comment: AFAIK this is the easiest way if you need to execute a serious regex to match a certain name